# How to give border to a shape?

Tags: css

I am building a testimonial component in react and I have to make a shape direction towards pic, I have done the shape exactly how I want but the testimonial div has border color when I apply the div gets a border but the shape is left outside I have tried several ways but couldn't find a solution, I have attached the picture of what I want and how it is right now.

[How I want it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYdyk.png)

[image: How I want it]

[What I have achieved till now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FwPVh.png)
[image: What I have achieved till now]

Below is my CSS

```css
#page {
  background-color: lightgray;
  padding: 40px;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  max-width: 600px;
  height: auto;
  border: 1px solid #E7E7E7;
  padding: 30px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container:after {
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 50px solid white;
  border-right: 40px solid transparent;
  top:101%;
  left: 40%;
  content: '';
  transform: rotate(14deg);
  margin-top: -10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="page">
  <div class="container">This is a test</div>
</div>
```

Comment: hey upload your code not only css

Comment: Use box shadow, a bit tricky but it can do the work!

Comment: @BurhanKashour Box Shadow to what?

Comment: @m4n0 I misunderstood you. I thought you need a border for the big box.

Comment: @BurhanKashour Well, I did not write the question but yeah! :)

Answer (score 2):

You may use a [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter) , choice: [`drop-shadow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter-function/drop-shadow).

support ? , don't be afraid : https://caniuse.com/?search=drop-shadow  *All but **IE 6-11** and **Opera mini***

here is an exemple to run:

```css
#page {
  background-color: lightgray;
  padding: 40px;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  max-width: 600px;
  height: auto;
 filter:
 /* draw borders without blur*/
     drop-shadow(0 1px  )
     drop-shadow(1px 0px )
     drop-shadow(0 -1px  )
     drop-shadow(-1px 0px )
     /* add eventually a shadow */
     drop-shadow(0 0 3px )
     /*and  another for demo purpose */     
     drop-shadow(30px 30px 3px gray );
  padding: 30px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container:after {
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 50px solid white;
  border-right: 40px solid transparent;
  top:101%;
  left: 40%;
  content: '';
  transform: rotate(14deg);
  margin-top: -10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="page">
  <div class="container">This is a test</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Careful with your browser compatibility with using filter: https://caniuse.com/?search=css%20filter

Comment: @PhilB. if you mind IE11 and less and also Opera mini : https://caniuse.com/?search=drop-shadow  ;) but then, it doesn't destroy anything and i believe is not a bad practice : https://alistapart.com/article/progressiveenhancementwithcss/

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `:before` that's 1px bigger than your `:after` which uses the border colour instead and then it will be mostly covered by the `:after`, giving you your "fake" border. Just makes sure your z-indexing is correct so it doesn't show inside your bubble.

**EDIT:** Adding in example css.

I modified some colours and spacing for illustrative purposes:

```css
#page {
  background: #ffc;
  padding: 40px 40px 60px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  background: #fff;
  max-width: 600px;
  height: auto;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 30px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container:after,
.container:before {
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  top: 101%;
  left: 40%;
  content: "";
  transform: rotate(14deg);
  margin-top: -10px;
}

.container:after {
  border-top: 50px solid #fff;
  border-right: 40px solid transparent;

}

.container:before {
  border-top: 52px solid #000;
  border-right: 42px solid transparent;
  margin-left: -1px;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div id="page">
  <div class="container">This is a test</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice explanation but it would be better if you can modify the code and show it to them.

Answer (score 0):

Adding both a :before and :after is a good idea to get the effect you want. Using a CSS `box-shadow or outline` won't work because it actually renders a complete square around your arrow/triangle shape. A z-index is added to the before to push it to the background. In that way it's not overlapping the other objects.

Here's an example of what you might want. You can adjust the border sizes to finetune it.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  max-width: 600px;
  height: auto;
  border: 1px solid #E7E7E7;
  padding: 30px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container:before {
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 53px solid #e7e7e7;
  border-right: 43px solid transparent;
  top: 100%;
  left: 40%;
  content: '';
  transform: rotate(14deg);
  margin-top: -10px;
  z-index: -1;
}

.container:after {
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 50px solid white;
  border-right: 40px solid transparent;
  top:101%;
  left: 40%;
  content: '';
  transform: rotate(14deg);
  margin-top: -10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
```